# Replace class implementation with Scala Macro

Tags: scala, macros

I have to implement a Macro which replaces the implementation of a class by a class of another implementation, if a library does not exist. The reason is that users might not be willing to install a complex library (say the name is complex.jar). It is very important that the code **compiles** even if the library is not present.

Practical Example: 
Think of e.g. a tool for computing complex mathematical functions. Let us assume that we now want to add the functionality of plotting the result. For this we use Matlab (I know there are others, this is just an example). Let us assume that Matlab has a jar file. Since not all users have Matlab installed, I want that my code compiles also without this jar although it uses Methods from this jar.

Example:

```
@ReplaceMeIfLibDoesNotExist("complex","DefaultConnector.scala")
class ComplexConnector{
   import complex._;
   def connect(){
      complex = new ComplexLibrary(); // part of complex.jar
   }
}

class DefaultConnector{
   def connect(){
      println("Currently not supported. Install complex.jar")
   }
}
```

Would something like that work? How would the Macro implementation look like? Or is there some more elegant way of doing things like that? It would be nice to have a concrete code example.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am very much a fan of Scala's macro system, but this is terrifying.

Comment: What do you mean by terrifying? Is this too difficult? Or bad style? What do you do in such a case? Can you do something better without Macros?

Comment: It sounds like you're essentially bullying the compiler into saying yes to something that you and it both know may blow up down the line. It feels like a throwback to the bad old days of configuring your Java program with class names read at runtime from strings.

Comment: The idea is that this will be part of a larger project where the library 'complex' is not neccessary to do the main work with the tool. However, if users want to increase speed for a specific task, they **may** load one library. This library has a quite complex installation process which not every user should be forced to do (especially if he does not need the functionality). I tried to made it clearer above including an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a macro is appropriate for this - macros act at compile time, whereas it sounds like you want to change functionality based on which libraries are available at runtime. I would suggest something along the lines of SLF4J's static binding approach - load the ComplexLibrary via a static method which is implemented differently in your connector-complex.jar from your base jar.